# Jquery - scroll to top plugin with the box at the top

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin, which scrolls the page to the top by clicking on a box (I sow the one on godaddy.com - don't like the idea of the box being at the bottom of the page, the box needs it to be at the top of the page strictly)

Here's an example:
http://lenta.ru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a plugin:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
});
```

You could also use:

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("element").offset().top }, 1000);
```

Where `element` is an element on the page. Then it will scroll to that element's location. Change `1000` to the number of milliseconds you want the animation to span. `1000` = 1 second.